# On Windows 7 x64, how to run JDK/JRE 6 for applet, but run JDK 7 for anything else?

Tags: java, java-applet

We intend to use JDK 7 for our development use. But there is a dumb (but critical) web applet application which relies on JDK/JRE 6 (otherwise it won't run). I only need the JDK/JRE 6 applet to run in either IE or Firefox. How to do this?

Comment: Install only the JRE 6 browser plugin?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Where to obtain the plugin?

Comment: From the JRE 6 installer?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Where to find the manual for this kind of hackie installation? Browser wizard always guides me to download the latest Java version (i.e Java 7).

Comment: Wouldn't know .

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Or perhaps do you know which files need to be copied from JRE 6 folder to the IE or Firefox folder?

Comment: No, I haven't actually used JRE 6 for... a very long time.

Comment: The best solution we have found (other than dropping Java, which sadly is not possible) is to install all required versions and just enable / disable as required from the java cpl

Comment: @AthomSfere: To run applet, does IE or Firefox need the JRE/bin in the Path and the JRE folder in JAVA_HOME?

Comment: When you install them, it will add additional JAVA paths, yes. Or with some you can install, then in the CPL add -> existing and point it to the older version. Unfortunately with Java you have to try, test, see how broken everything is and adjust

Comment: IE: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/family-clsid-140615.html

Comment: http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/63-how-to-use-java-applets-in-modern-browsers.html

Comment: The Java 6 browser plugin does not allow the kind of control the Java 7 browser addon allows.  You will have problems doing this.  Why do you want to use an insecure version of Java for?